# FIXML XML validation using JAXB

Tags: xml, validation, jaxb, schema, fix-protocol

I have the following code:

```
public class XMLValidationTest {

    private static Schema schema;

    @BeforeAll
    static void initClass() throws SAXException {
        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        schemaFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/honour-all-schemaLocations", true);
        // File xsdDirectory = new
        // File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("xsd").getPath());
        // Schema schema = schemaFactory
        // .newSchema(Stream.of(xsdDirectory.listFiles()).map(f -> new StreamSource(f))
        // .toArray(Source[]::new));
        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new StreamSource(
            Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xsd/fixml-main-Latest.xsd")));
    }

    @Test
    void testXMLValidation() throws SAXException, IOException {
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(
            Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("PtyDetlDefReq.xml")));
    }
}
```

The following schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
        FIXML Schema Version FIX.Latest EP269 

        Generated: 2021-09-01T22:30:17.202Z

        Copyright(c) FIX Protocol Limited. All rights reserved.

        Comments and errors should be posted on the FIX protocol web-site http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org
-->

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-Latest"
           xmlns:fm="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-Latest/METADATA"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-Latest/METADATA fixml-metadata-Latest.xsd"
           targetNamespace="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-Latest"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
   <xs:include schemaLocation="fixml-pretrade-Latest.xsd"/>
   <xs:include schemaLocation="fixml-trade-Latest.xsd"/>
   <xs:include schemaLocation="fixml-posttrade-Latest.xsd"/>
   <xs:include schemaLocation="fixml-infrastructure-Latest.xsd"/>
</xs:schema>
```

All schema is in project:

[image: XSD files]

When I try validating the following valid xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fixp:FIXML xmlns:fixp="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-Latest" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" v="FIXT.1.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-Latest fixml-main-Latest.xsd ">
    <fixp:PtyDetlDefReq ReqID="cdd65c40-d70b-4f01-b022-3992eb4db1b8">
        <fixp:PtyDetlUpd ListUpdActn="M">
            <fixp:PtyDetl ID="some tax ID" Src="J" R="5" Qual="24">
                <fixp:Sub ID="Diego" Typ="78"/>
                <fixp:Sub ID="Alcorta" Typ="79"/>
                <fixp:Sub ID="1979-10-24" Typ="80"/>
                <fixp:Sub ID="Y" Typ="2"/>
                <fixp:Sub ID="Ciudad Autonoma de Buenos Aires" Typ="34"/>
                <fixp:Sub ID="Ciudad Autonoma de Buenos Aires" Typ="35"/>
                <fixp:Sub ID="C1417BSY" Typ="36"/>
                <fixp:Sub ID="Desaguadero 3465" Typ="37"/>
                <fixp:Sub ID="AR" Typ="38"/>
                <fixp:AltPty ID="some personal ID" Typ="Q"/>
            </fixp:PtyDetl>
        </fixp:PtyDetlUpd>
    </fixp:PtyDetlDefReq>
</fixp:FIXML>
```

I get the following error if I read all files from resource directory (commented code):
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 67; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-Latest":PtyDetlDefReq}'. One of '{"http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-Latest":Message, "http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-Latest":Batch}' is expected.]

PtyDetlDefReq is an extension of Message.

If I load only the main xsd (uncommented code), I get the following error:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 217; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'fixp:FIXML'.]

The full schema can be downloaded from:
https://www.fixtrading.org/standards/fixml/

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That page requires a login to download files.

Comment: Worth reading about xml catalog I believe: https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/03/03/catalogs.html

Comment: I made the code easier to test, and the registration is free since it is a open spec (ISO 20022) for anyone to download

Comment: May be `xsd/fixml-main-Latest.xsd` is not the right schema to validate that xml. Which xsd defines `PtyDetlDefReq`? then go upstream on the xsd structure.

Answer (score 0):

I have to change this line:

```
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new StreamSource(
            Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xsd/fixml-main-Latest.xsd")));
```

To this line to make it work:

```
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(
            Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("xsd/fixml-main-Latest.xsd"));
```

By making it an URL it can transverse all the files in the resource folder.